# From Android I want to call API with POST method

Tags: android, api, post

I am getting response from API when I submit request from Postman like shown in the image

screenshot1.jpg = The data I need to pass
screenshot2.jpg = The result we get

[image: screenshot1.jpg]
[image: screenshot2.jpg]

I tried calling them through android with below code but it's not working,

```
JSONObject login = new JSONObject();
login.put("username", userName);
login.put("password", password);
login.put("platform", "ANDROID");
login.put("location", "56.1603092,10.2177147");

String str = WebServices.excutePost(url, login);


public static String excutePost(String targetURL, JSONObject urlParameters) {
    URL url;
    HttpURLConnection connection = null;
    try {


        //Create connection
        url = new URL(targetURL);
        connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        connection.setRequestMethod("POST");
        connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type",
                "application/raw");

        connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Length", "" +
                Integer.toString(urlParameters.toString().getBytes().length));
        connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Language", "en-US");


        connection.setUseCaches(false);
        connection.setDoInput(true);
        connection.setDoOutput(true);


        //Send request

        OutputStream out = new BufferedOutputStream(connection.getOutputStream());
        BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(out, "UTF-8"));
        writer.write(String.valueOf(urlParameters.toString().getBytes("UTF-8")));
        out.close();
        //connection.disconnect();

        //Get Response
        InputStream is = connection.getInputStream();
        BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
        String line;
        StringBuffer response = new StringBuffer();
        while ((line = rd.readLine()) != null) {
            response.append(line);
            response.append('\r');
        }
        rd.close();
        return response.toString();

    } catch (Exception e) {

        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;

    } finally {

        if (connection != null) {
            connection.disconnect();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you elaborate on 'not working'? What is it doing or not doing? Is there an error message?

Comment: I think your content type should be application/json

Comment: can you provide the stacktrace for the issue if possible ?

Comment: have you tried output.writeBytes(String.valueOf(urlParameters.toString().getBytes("UTF-8")));

Answer (score 3):

You can use below method:

```
public String executePost(String targetURL,String urlParameters) {
    int timeout=5000;
    URL url;
    HttpURLConnection connection = null;
    try {
        // Create connection

        url = new URL(targetURL);
        connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        connection.setRequestMethod("POST");
        connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type",
                "application/json");

        connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Length",
                "" + Integer.toString(urlParameters.getBytes().length));
        connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Language", "en-US");

        connection.setUseCaches(false);
        connection.setDoInput(true);
        connection.setDoOutput(true);
        connection.setConnectTimeout(timeout);
        connection.setReadTimeout(timeout);

        // Send request
        DataOutputStream wr = new DataOutputStream(
                connection.getOutputStream());
        wr.writeBytes(urlParameters);
        wr.flush();
        wr.close();

        // Get Response
        InputStream is = connection.getInputStream();
        BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
        String line;
        StringBuffer response = new StringBuffer();
        while ((line = rd.readLine()) != null) {
            response.append(line);
            response.append('\r');
        }
        rd.close();
        return response.toString();

    } catch (SocketTimeoutException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();

    } catch (MalformedURLException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(getClass().getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException ex) {

        Logger.getLogger(getClass().getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {

        if (connection != null) {
            connection.disconnect();
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

You can create URL parameters like:

```
JSONObject loginParams = new JSONObject();
loginParams .put("username", userName);
loginParams .put("password", password);
loginParams .put("platform", "ANDROID");
loginParams .put("location", "56.1603092,10.2177147");
```

Calling method like:

```
executePost(serviceURL,loginParams.toString());
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [retrofit](http://square.github.io/retrofit/) library for easier to implement network communication with REST Service.

By the way, you can try my solution for your problem:

- **First**, create an executeHttp method

  ```
          private JSONObject executeHttp(HttpUriRequest request, Context context) throws ClientProtocolException, IOException {
          HttpParams httpParameters = new BasicHttpParams();
              // Set the timeout in milliseconds until a connection is established.
              // The default value is zero, that means the timeout is not used.
              int timeoutConnection = 3000;
              HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(httpParameters, timeoutConnection);
              // Set the default socket timeout (SO_TIMEOUT)
              // in milliseconds which is the timeout for waiting for data.
              int timeoutSocket = 10000;
              HttpConnectionParams.setSoTimeout(httpParameters, timeoutSocket);

              DefaultHttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient(httpParameters);
              // add your header in here - I saw your header has 7 params
              request.addHeader("Authorization", getToken());
              request.addHeader("APIKey", API_KEY);
              request.addHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
              request.addHeader("X-Request-Mime-Type", "application/json;");
              HttpResponse execute = client.execute(request);
              InputStream content = execute.getEntity().getContent();
              // implement your handle response here, below is just an example
              try {
                   return new JSONObject().put("content", this.convertStreamToByteArray(content));
              } catch (JSONException e) {
              //Crashlytics.logException(e);
                   Log.e(LOG_TAG, "Error converting stream to byte array: " + e.getMessage());
                   return new JSONObject();

              }
          }
  ```

**Then** create a method to handle POST request

```
public JSONObject doPost(List<NameValuePair> headerParams, List<NameValuePair> parameters, String url, Context context) throws ClientProtocolException, IOException {
        HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);
        // add the header if needed
        if (headerParams != null) {
            for (NameValuePair headerParam: headerParams) {
                httpPost.addHeader(headerParam.getName(), headerParam.getValue());
            }
        }
        httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(parameters, "UTF-8"));

        return executeHttp(httpPost, context);
    }
```

**Finally**, call the api just created.

```
JSONObject json = doPost(header, nameValuePairs, yourUrl, context);
```

with nameValuePairs is created by

```
            List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("username", userName));
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password", password));
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("platform", "ANDROID"));
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("location", "56.1603092,10.2177147"));
```

Answer (score 0):

Issue was using the stringbuffer class, I used string to get response and it worked perfectly. Thank you every one for comments and answers.