# How to send a Base64 String to an API (MathPix OCR)?

Tags: java, api, base64

I'm an absolute newbie in Java / Android Studio and happy to achive my first results.
My app is able to capture a foto and convert it into a Base64 string. Now I have to send this string to the MathPix API. 
They got a documentation on their site https://docs.mathpix.com/ but it doesn't help me much.

Can someone help?

Thanks a lot and have a nice weekend!

Adrian

Comment: Can you please elaborate. What exactly do you want to do? What have you tried so far? Can you also please provide your code, that you have problems with? Pinpoint the line, if you can.

Comment: Have you read the api doc you linked in your question? It's pretty clear that they expect jpg image data posted to the endpoint. So why do you base64 encode your data? Stack Overflow is a community of people who are certainly willing to help, but a minimum effort on your side is required. So please show us what you tried (especially your code) and what exactly your problem is. That will help us a lot to come up with support for your problem

Comment: Hey Lutz, Hey Korashen, thanks for your comments. First: I dont have any code to call the API yet because I dont know how to do it. I've done some research and found only huge examples how to send a Base64 to a server or a website. 
There is a tutorial how to do it with python and it has less then 20 lines and it worked very well (https://www.letsrockinformatik.de/bilderkennung-von-formeln-mit-python-via-mathpix)
For a noob like me it tooked 2 weeks of work to let my app take a foto, crop it and encode it in base64 - there is a mimimum effort :P

Comment: Second: In the documentation stands: "src": "data:image/jpeg;base64,..." Doesn't it mean, that I need to send a Base64 string? The python example works this way. 

I dont ask you to do my work, only for some advice or a helpfull link. Maybe there is a good book with the right chapter I need? 

If there's a code from me, I will post it here :)

Comment: And the doc sounds pretty clear, but I dont know how to implement it in my Java code

Answer (score -1):

You just need to send a POST request to the API.

The following answer is a good example of how it can be done.
[From Android I want to call API with POST method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35030360/from-android-i-want-to-call-api-with-post-method)